# In what order does TensorFlow evaluate nodes in a computation graph?

Tags: tensorflow

I am having a strange bug in TensorFlow. Consider the following code, part of a simple feed-forward neural network:

```
output = (tf.matmul(layer_3,w_out) + b_out)
prob = tf.nn.sigmoid(output);
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = output, targets = y_, name=None))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(loss, var_list = model_variables)`
```

(Notice that prob is not used to define the loss function. This is because sigmoid_cross_entropy applies sigmoid internally in its definition)
I later run the optimizer in the following line:

```
result,step_loss,_ = sess.run(fetches = [output,loss,optimizer],feed_dict = {x_ : np.array([[x,y,x*x,y*y,x*y]]), y_ : [[1,0]]});
```

The above works just fine. However, if I instead run the following line to run the code, the network seems to perform terribly, even though there shouldn't be any difference!

```
result,step_loss,_ = sess.run(fetches = [prob,loss,optimizer],feed_dict = {x_ : np.array([[x,y,x*x,y*y,x*y]]), y_ : [[1,0]]});
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with the order in which TF computes the nodes in the graph during a session, but I'm not sure. What could the issue be?

Answer (score 0):

It's not an issue with the graph, it's just that you are looking at different things.

In the first example you provide:

`result,step_loss,_ = sess.run(fetches = [output,loss,optimizer],feed_dict = {x_ : np.array([[x,y,x*x,y*y,x*y]]), y_ : [[1,0]]})`

you are saving the result of running the `output` op in the `result` python variable.

In the second one:

`result,step_loss,_ = sess.run(fetches = [prob,loss,optimizer],feed_dict = {x_ : np.array([[x,y,x*x,y*y,x*y]]), y_ : [[1,0]]})`

you are saving the result of the `prob` op in the `result` python variable.

Since both ops are different it is to be expected that the values returned by them would be different.

You could run

`logits, activation, step_loss, _ = sess.run(fetches = [output, prob, loss, optimizer], ...)`

to check your results.

Comment: The problem is that when I run against the testing set, I do not use prob at  all. In fact, I use the following to test:   `result= sess.run(fetches = output, feed_dict = {x_ : [[X_, Y_, X_*X_, Y_*Y_, X_*Y_]]});`                                             I don't use prob anywhere when I am testing. Yet replacing output with prob in the fetch during training causes the testing stage to become poorly performing.